# Nuget install of of Entity Framework Core SQL Server in VS for OSX causing build errors

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi

I am having an issue when installing `Entity Framework Core MSSQL` in Visual Studio 2017 for OSX.

I run the below command and the package install correctly, but a few seconds later I get red (build?) errors showing up in all `cs` files.

What can I do to clear these errors?

`dotnet add core-udemy package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

Output

```
 ~/Projects/core-udemy  ⑂ master +    
dotnet add core-udemy package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
  Writing /var/folders/fw/_y4_qxxd2ls2lh_dmwrdlp000000gn/T/tmpO0Tl4b.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' into project '/Users/richardcurteis/Projects/core-udemy/core-udemy/core-udemy.csproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for /Users/richardcurteis/Projects/core-udemy/core-udemy/core-udemy.csproj...
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver/index.json
warn : Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 requires Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0) but version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.3 was resolved.
error: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.3 directly to project core-udemy to resolve this issue. 
error:  core-udemy -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.3 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.2.3 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.3) 
error:  core-udemy -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0).
info : Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project '/Users/richardcurteis/Projects/core-udemy/core-udemy/core-udemy.csproj'.
info : PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' version '2.2.3' added to file '/Users/richardcurteis/Projects/core-udemy/core-udemy/core-udemy.csproj'.
info : Committing restore...
log  : Generating MSBuild file /Users/richardcurteis/Projects/core-udemy/core-udemy/obj/core-udemy.csproj.nuget.g.props.
info : Writing lock file to disk. Path: /Users/richardcurteis/Projects/core-udemy/core-udemy/obj/project.assets.json
log  : Restore failed in 1.83 sec for /Users/richardcurteis/Projects/core-udemy/core-udemy/core-udemy.csproj.
```

My code then displays this on all class declarations...

```
Error: The type or namespace 'IConfiguration could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Error: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

Error: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
```

[image]

And

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the error of "**Version conflict detected**" happens because there's something wrong with the versions of dependency graph.

> error: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.3 directly to project core-udemy to resolve this issue.
>
> error:  core-udemy -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.3 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.2.3 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.3)
>
> error:  core-udemy -> **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1** -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore **(>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0)**.

1. As the information describes, your project depends on the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App v2.1.1`, which requires the version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`  **(2.1.1 && < 2.2.0)**.
2. However, by using `dotnet add core-udemy package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, you're installing the "current" version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`. The following screenshot from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.0.0-preview3.19153.1) shows that you're installing the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` **(2.2.3)** :

[image]

Since you're using `ASP.NET Core 2.1`, **you could install the related packages with an option of `--version 2.1.*`** :

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --version 2.1.*
```

It will result in a dependency as below:

```
<ItemGroup>

    ...

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Once you fix the version conflict, you could run `dotnet clean` & `dotnet restore` & `dotnet build`, and then the second question will be solved.

---

Besides, the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`**(v2.1.1)** meta package has already set a dependency on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0)` :

[image]

you don't need add such a package reference manually.